# Bash command and order of options

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I issue:

```
bash -l -c "./test"
```

the subshell is indeed run as a login shell, but in a case:

```
bash -c "./test1" -l
```

the parent shell (the shell I'm running the command) seems to ignore `-l` option and the subshell isn't run as a login shell.

If I'm right, the reason is that the order of the options to the `bash` command is relevant and in this case the `-l` option has to be before `-c`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `-c string`
>   If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from `string`. If there are arguments after the `string`, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

This means that `bash -c 'echo $0' -l` returns `-l`.

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Unix commands is that file names come last (because many commands can take an almost unlimited number of filenames). In other words, the first thing that doesn't look like a flag/option is interpreted as a filename[1] and so is everything that follows it.

[1] If you use a file that starts with a dash, you can disambiguate it in two ways:

- using `./-foo` instead of `-foo`: `rm ./-foobar`
- using a '--' at the end of the true options since many commands interpret this as the end of the options and the beginning of the file names:  `rm -- -foobar`. Good script coding practices recommend using the `--` "fence" in commands where the file names aren't predetermined.

Comment: Your answer seems to be inadequate to the question. (1) There is a convention you mentioned but it applies to filenames that are *"loose"* i.e. not associated to a preceding option; `bash -c` requires *something*. (2) The required argument to `bash -c` may not be a file (it's a command in general) and the behavior will be the same, this is all the more reason the convention doesn't apply here. (3) Compare `grep -f`. It requires a filename and *doesn't* influence options that follow. In fact this is more common behavior and `bash -c` is rather unique. (4) You didn't answer the question.

Comment: Somewhat inadequate to the actual question, but definitely the answer that will be useful to all the people to get here based on the (rather ambiguous) title. Note also the use of "many" and not of "all".